# Schema name in Create index statement while generating datanucleus JDO schema

Tags: mysql, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to generate schema from the DataNucleus SchemaTool for a mysql database, that will store countries and states. Here is a sample of that code:

```
@PersistenceCapable
Public class State{
    private String shortCode;
    private String fullName;
    @Column(allowsNull = "true",name="country_id")
    private Country countryId;
}
```

The following are my schemaGeneration properties:

```
datanucleus.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datanucleus.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/geog
datanucleus.ConnectionUserName=geog
datanucleus.ConnectionPassword=geogPass
datanucleus.schema.validateTables=true
datanucleus.mapping.Catalog=geog
datanucleus.mapping.Schema=geog
```

In my Country class as well, I have a mapping from a Collection, so that the FK reference for States to the Country table is built correctly.

But there is one problem. In the SQL script generated, the Index part has the Schema name as part of the index name itself, which fails the entire script. Here is that piece:

```
CREATE INDEX `GEOG`.`MST_STATE_N49` ON `GEOG`.`MST_STATE` (`COUNTRY_ID`);
```

Notice the schema name in the `GEOG`.`MST_STATE_N49` part of the index' name.

I tried setting the schema and catalog name to blank but that yields a ''.`MST_STATE_N49` which still fails.

I am using MySQL Server 5.7.17 using the 5.1.42 version of the JDBC driver (yes, not the latest) on Data nucleus JDO 3.1

Any hints on how I can get rid of the schema/catalog name in the generated DDL?

Comment: Why are you putting "datanucleus.mapping.Schema" when using MySQL ? It doesnt use schema last I looked. Similarly the "datanucleus.mapping.Catalog" is effectively defined by your URL!

Comment: 1. Removed both the schemaName and the catalogName and it worked. Thank you.

I knew that the schema property was not being used. The tool ended up using catalogName. That is the other linked question bugging me. MySQL supports only schemaNames. But still, the MySQL Adapter for DataNucleus says that it only supports CatalogNames. It does not seem that the choice was erroneous and may have actually been deliberate. Can somebody please explain the reason (if any)?

Comment: MySQL only actually supports JDBC catalog, mapping on to "database", as per this post https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,137564,137629#msg-137629 Since DataNucleus simply uses the JDBC driver then catalog is the only useful input

Comment: Thanks. Can you please place your comment in an answer? I can as an alternate mark my own answer as the solution tomorrow (because it does not allow me today)

Thank you for both the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you putting "datanucleus.mapping.Schema" when using MySQL ? MySQL doesnt use schema last I looked. Similarly the "datanucleus.mapping.Catalog" is effectively defined by your URL! MySQL only actually supports JDBC catalog, mapping on to "database", as per this [post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,137564,137629#msg-137629). Since DataNucleus simply uses the JDBC driver then catalog is the only useful input.

Consequently removal of both schema and catalog properties will DEFAULT to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

After the comment above from Neil Stockton, I commented out both the properties and it worked. Effectively, this is what is needed:

```
datanucleus.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datanucleus.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/geog
datanucleus.ConnectionUserName=geog
datanucleus.ConnectionPassword=geogPass
datanucleus.schema.validateTables=true
```

Hopefully, I can get the answer to the other question (Pt. 2 in my reply-comment above) as well.